# Activator new command throws ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'activator.timeout'

Tags: playframework-2.0

I followed the Play documentation to get started.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Installing

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/NewApplication

when running the command:

> activator new myApp play-java

I'm Gettting the error:

**"Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting"**

Details about my environment.

OS        : Windows 7 32bits

Activator : typesafe-activator-1.2.10.zip

Java      : jdk1.6.0_31

I have read and write permission over the directory of installation. It is in D:\play\activator

Installation process:

1. Downloaded Activator from : http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.2.10/typesafe-activator-1.2.10.zip
2. Unziped it to **D:\play\activator**
3. Added that directory to the PATH environment variable
4. Command typed: **activator help**

   Usage activator [options] [command]

   Commands:
   ui                 Start the Activator UI
   new [name] [template-id]  Create a new project with [name] using template [templ
   ate-id]
   list-templates     Print all available template names
   help               Print this message

   Options:
   -jvm-debug [port]  Turn on JVM debugging, open at the given port.  Defaults to 9
   999 if no port given.

   Environment variables (read from context):
   JAVA_OPTS          Environment variable, if unset uses ""
   SBT_OPTS           Environment variable, if unset uses ""
   ACTIVATOR_OPTS     Environment variable, if unset uses ""
5. trying to create a new project

   **d:\play\activator> activator new myApp play-java**

   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                   at activator.ActivatorCliHelper$class.$init$(ActivatorCliHelper.scala:14
           )
                   at activator.ActivatorCli$.(ActivatorCli.scala:16)
                   at activator.ActivatorCli$.(ActivatorCli.scala)
                   at activator.ActivatorLauncher.run(ActivatorLauncher.scala:28)
                   at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
                   at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
                   at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
                   at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
                   at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
                   at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
                   at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
                   at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
                   at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
           **Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'activator.timeout'**
                   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
                   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:145)
                   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:151)
                   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
                   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
                   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getDuration(SimpleConfig.java:2
           60)
                   at activator.ActivatorCliHelper$.(ActivatorCliHelper.scala:31)
                   at activator.ActivatorCliHelper$.(ActivatorCliHelper.scala)
                   ... 13 more
           Error during sbt execution: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Any idea about what am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: On which OS? Which version of Activator? Where/how did you install activator so that it's on your path?

activator.timeout isn't something you should have to configure, it's something that should be embedded in the activator jars. So something about your classpath or your install is somehow unusual. I don't have a good guess but if you tell us as much as you can maybe someone can figure it out. May also be helpful to post the full output of activator new, not only the error.

Comment: Thank you Havoc!. I have updated the question adding more details about it. Any suggestion? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I removed variable JAVA_OPTS and restarted the computer :S.

that worked. Thank you